# SSIS Move Data Between Databases - Maintain Referential Integrity

Tags: sql-server, ssis, foreign-keys, sql-server-data-tools, control-flow

I need to move data between two databases and wanted to see if SSIS would be a good tool. I've pieced together the following solution, but it is much more complex than I was hoping it would be - any insight on a better approach to tackling this problem would be greatly appreciated!

So what makes my situation unique; we have a large volume of data, so to keep the system performant we have split our customers into multiple database servers. These servers have databases with the same schema, but are each populated with unique data. Occasionally we have the need to move a customer's data from one server to another. Because of this, simple recreating the tables and moving the data in place won't work as in the database on server A there could be 20 records, but there could be 30 records in the same table for the database on server B. So when moving record 20 from A to B, *it will need to be assigned ID 31*. Getting past this wasn't difficult, but the trouble comes when needing to move the tables which have a foreign key reference to what is now record 31....

An example:
Here's a sample schema for a simple example:

[image: Sample Schema]

There is a table to track manufacturers, and a table to track products which each reference a manufacturer.

Example of data in the source database:

[image: Source Data]

To handle moving this data while maintaining relational integrity, I've taken the approach of gathering the manufacturer records, looping through them, and for each manufacturer moving the associated products. Here's a high level look at the Control Flow in SSDT:

[image: Control Flow]

The first Data Flow grabs the records from the source database and pulls them into a Recordset Destination:

[image: Manufacturer Data Flow]

The OLE DB Source pulls from the source databases manufacturer table while pulling all columns, and places it into a record set:

[image: Manufacturer Data Flow Details]

Back in the control flow, I then loop through the records in the Manufacturer recordset:

[image: Manufacturer Foreach Loop]

For each record in the manufacturer recordset I then execute a SQL task which determines what the next available auto-incrementing ID will be in the destination database, inserts the record, and then returns the results of a SELECT MAX(ManufacturerID) in the Execute SQL Task result set so that the newly created Manufacturer ID can be used when inserting the related products into the destination database:

[image: Manufacturer Insert SQL Query]

The above *works*, however once you get more than a few layers deep of tables that reference one another, this is no longer very tenable. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could always try this:

1. Populate you manufacturers table.
2. Get your products data (ensure you have a reference such as name etc. to manufacturer)
3. Use a lookup to get the ID where your name or whatever you choose matches.
4. Insert into database.

This will keep your FK constraints and not require you to do all that max key selection.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Kyle - I had thought of that approach too, and it would likely work in most cases, but unfortunately there's always a chance the you would have multiple manufacturers with the same name. For example, Dove chocolate and Dove soap.

Comment: @mstendal I don't see the problem then because they still fall under the same manufacturer.

Comment: If we moved the entry for Dove soap to (name: 'Dove', ID: 1) to a new database (name: 'Dove', ID: 5), when we go to move product 'Bar of Soap' to the new database, your suggestion was that we lookup what manufacturer to use based on the non-primary key values of the manufacturer table to determine that the manufacturer 1 previously referenced by product 'Bar of Soap' is now manufacturer 5 in the new database. In the particular simplified example, we likely wouldn't have an instance where the name, address, primary contact, etc was the same between two manufacturers. But given the data in...

Comment: ... our production database, that won't always be the case. We cannot rely on non-primary key fields to unique identify a record in a particular table.

Comment: @mstendal That is ok I understand. Let put some more thought into it!